# How to get values from a dataframe column using SparkSQL?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Right now I am working with Spark/Scala and I am trying to join multiple dataframes to get the expected output.
The data input are CSV files with call record information. These are the input main fields.

a_number:String = is the origin call number.

area_code_a:String = is the a_number area code.

prefix_a:String = is the a_number prefix.

b_number:String = is the destination call number.

area_code_b:String = is the b_number area code.

prefix_b:String = is the b_number prefix.

cause_value:String = is the call final status.

```
val dfint = ((cdrs_nac.join(grupos_nac).where(col("causevalue") === col("id")))
    .join(centrales_nac, col("dpc") === col("pointcode_decimal"), "left")
    .join(series_nac_a).where(col("area_code_a") === col("codigo_area") && 
        col("prefix_a") === col("prefijo") && 
        col("series_a") >= col("serie_inicial") && 
        col("series_a") <= col("serie_final"))
    .join(series_nac_b, (
        ((col("codigo_area_b") === col("area_code_b")) && col("len_b_number") == "8") || 
        ((col("codigo_area_b") === col("area_code_b")) && col("len_b_number") == "10") || 
        ((col("codigo_area_b") === col("codigo_area_cent")) && col("len_b_number") == "7")) && 
        col("prefix_b") === col("prefijo_b") && 
        col("series_b") >= col("serie_inicial_b") && 
        col("series_b") <= col("serie_final_b"), "left")
```

This generates a multiple output files with the call data records processed, including the column "len_b_number" which means the length of the b_number field.

I was doing some tests I already find that for some reason the expression **"col("len_b_number")"** is returning the column name **"len_b_number"** instead the length values which are 7, 8 or 10. This means that the col("len_b_number") == 7  OR col("len_b_number") == 8 OR col("len_b_number") == 10 conditions will never work because the code will always compare with the column name.

At this moment the output is blank because the col("len_b_number") doesnt match with 7, 8 or 10. I will like to know if ypou can help to understand how to extract the value from this column.

Thanks

Comment: I think you mean conditions.

Comment: Sorry about the first post. I hope that this time the explanation is more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using === instead of ==.

I could not get your error.

```
&& col("len_b_number") == "8"
```

should be:

```
&& col("len_b_number") === "8"
```